# Nodejs creatng connection factory

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have connection with db2 following way which works fine

```
require("ifxnjs").open(connectionString, function(err, con){  
    If(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        con.query(........){
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to create a separate connection factory that can be called in any query. The code I have is

```
function confactory(){
    db=require("ifxnjs).open(connectionString, function(err, conn){
        if(err){} else {
           console.log('connected');
        }
    })
    return db
}
module.exports=confactory();
```

Than I access the connection in project

```
 var db=require('./cofactory.js');
 db.query('select * from emp', function(err, result){
       if(err){}
          else { cons
      }
 })
```

When I run the program I get error for 
TypeError Can not read property 'query' of undefined
Please let me know how I can fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: `db=equire` That probably won't work.

Comment: `con.query(........)` is "........" a query?

Comment: The posted code is too fragmentary, and has too many basic typos, for us to help you. Please use copy and paste and then remove the unnecessary bits. Please also ensure the code is formatted and indented in a consistent way so it can be more easily read.

Comment: The problem is that the database connection is created asynchronously, so you cannot get simply get the result and return it from your function. There are many ways to deal with this: callbacks, promises or async/await. Here is the most popular question/answer on Stack Overflow that explains it all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You're also missing a quote in `confactory()` after `db=require("ifxnjs`.